# What could cause my django admin to not render the default filter_horizontal only on production?

Tags: django

Django 1.6 admin comes with UserAdmin and GroupAdmin which have nicely separated `filter_horizontal` and fieldsets.

Somehow, only on production, my auth.User and auth.Group both render all fieldsets, but no filter_horizontal. No JS errors.

Since it loads fieldsets, it clearly is reading the `ModelAdmin` correctly. But why would `filter_horizontal` be specifically ignored?

When I run the same environment via `runserver` on the production server, I get the correct fields.

I have also unregistered the default admin, and defined my own `UserAdmin` with `filter_horizontal` with no success.

This seems to imply filter_horizontal is specifically not working for production (uwsgi) but working for runserver with the same environment.

My uWSGI environment should match exactly the `runserver`environment, as I only have django installed in one environment on this server.

`virtualenv=/home/yuji/.virtualenvs/grovemade`

Any ideas?

Comment: As usual, typing out questions on stackoverflow really helps to determine other issues.. the last thing I can think of that could cause this is cloudflare's asynchronous javascript loading system called rocket. Disabling and waiting to see results..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, answer was cloudflare. Cloudflare and django admin apparently do not play well.

Specifically, my setup

- Async JS loading: CF Rocket
- Django admin + django suit.

Solution: disable cloudflare.